# How to replace commas with white spaces in a csv, but inserting a different number of space after each column?

Tags: csv, awk, sed

I have a file in the following format:

```
s1,23,789  
s2,25,689
```

and I would like to transform it into a file in the following format:

```
s1      23  789  
s2      25  689
```

i.e 6 white spaces between the 1st and 2nd column and only 3 white spaces between the 2nd and 3rd column?

Is there a quick way of pulling this off using sed or awk?

Comment: See also the unix command `column -t ` if you just want to throw all even column formatting over to an existing command after you replace the commas.

Answer (score 4):

you can try with `sed`

```
sed -r 's/(\S+),(\S+),(\S+)/\1      \2   \3/g' file
```

or `awk` using [Modifiers for printf Formats](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Format-Modifiers.html)

```
awk -vFS="," '{printf "%2s%8s%5s\n",$1,$2,$3}' file
```

you get,

```
s1      23   789  
s2      25   689
```

Answer (score 2):

using awk it's as simple as

```
awk -F, '{ print $1,"      ",$2,"   ",$3 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

just for future seekers, I used the answer from Naumann and modified it to for my own use. My purpose is to remove commas between two columns and put a white space there.
The following worked for me:

```
awk -F, '{ print $1,$2 }' n64215_my_file_name.txt > log_new_file_name.txt
```